# OPENGL Fast Screen Recording of iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es

I'm new to OpenGL ES. I'm trying to write code for screen recording of iOS apps, especially games.

I'm using the 'render to texture' method described with code in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9704392/707773) to capture screen and write the video for a cocos2d game. One modification I made was that, when I call `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate` then I'm using `[EAGLContext currentContext]` instead of `[[GPUImageOpenGLESContext sharedImageProcessingOpenGLESContext] context]`

It does record the video but there are two issues

1. When it starts recording then new drawing on the screen stops. I want the app to keep on drawing on the screen too. As I'm new to OpenGL ES, I don't have deep understanding of frame buffer objects etc., so I have a hard time figuring out how to simultaneously draw on screen and capture the screen as well. I'll appreciate a code example in this regard.
2. The recorded video is flipped upside down. How can I get it in correct direction?

Previously I considered `glReadPixels` method too, but that has performance drawbacks.

Update: a couple of ideas also came to mind. According to my little understanding,

I could simply draw my texture back to screen, but don't know how.

UPDATE:
Main Draw

```
// ----- Display the keyframe -----
Texture* t = augmentationTexture[OBJECT_KEYFRAME_1 + playerIndex];
frameTextureID = [t textureID];
aspectRatio = (float)[t height] / (float)[t width];
texCoords = quadTexCoords;

// Get the current projection matrix
QCAR::Matrix44F projMatrix = vapp.projectionMatrix;

// If the current status is valid (not NOT_READY or ERROR), render the
// video quad with the texture we've just selected
if (NOT_READY != currentStatus) {
    // Convert trackable pose to matrix for use with OpenGL
    QCAR::Matrix44F modelViewMatrixVideo = QCAR::Tool::convertPose2GLMatrix(trackablePose);
    QCAR::Matrix44F modelViewProjectionVideo;

    // SampleApplicationUtils::translatePoseMatrix(0.0f, 0.0f, videoData[playerIndex].targetPositiveDimensions.data[0], &modelViewMatrixVideo.data[0]);
    SampleApplicationUtils :: scalePoseMatrix(videoData[playerIndex].targetPositiveDimensions.data[0], videoData[playerIndex].targetPositiveDimensions.data[0] * aspectRatio, videoData[playerIndex].targetPositiveDimensions.data[0], &modelViewMatrixVideo.data[0]);

    SampleApplicationUtils::multiplyMatrix(projMatrix.data, &modelViewMatrixVideo.data[0], &modelViewProjectionVideo.data[0]);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);

    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, quadVertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, quadNormals);
    glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, texCoords);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, frameTextureID);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat*) &modelViewProjectionVideo.data[0]);
    glUniform1i(texSampler2DHandle, 0 /*GL_TEXTURE0*/);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, kNumQuadIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, quadIndices);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

    glUseProgram(0);
}
```

Add the video texture buffer to the frame

```
glBindTexture([videoWriter textureCacheTarget], [videoWriter textureCacheID]);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, [videoWriter textureCacheID], 0);
```

Comment: in OpenGL bottom left is considered 0,0 while in viewcontrollers etc, top left is considered 0,0, so you are probably mapping the texture incorrectly, making it flip upside down

Comment: @Fonix close but that will not solve the issue. The texture is the source to generate the video so there is no texture mapping at this point. What needs to be done is flip the whole drawing to be upside down. All the buffers in openGL have the (0,0) on bottom left which is quite an inconvenience. Anyway usually Ortho or Frustum is used on which you need to flip the values top and bottom. Then when you draw this FBO texture to the display buffer you need to flip the coordinates so that texture (0,0) is at bottom left.

Comment: @vincent What issues are you having with simply drawing a resulting texture? Just bind the texture, bind the main buffer and draw the texture with full screen coordinates.

Comment: @MaticOblak can i know where the texture can draw to? because the main screen already drawed some other than i have recording thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "where the texture can draw to"? The texture will act exactly as any other texture. You may draw it anywhere you please. In your case that seems to be the full main buffer but it is not limited to that. For what I care it can be a part of a 3D scene where you drawn a whole office and the video is playing on a small model representing your phone on the desk...

Comment: @MaticOblak when i call     glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, [videoWriter textureCacheID], 0);, then main open gl screen will be stop to draw, how can i fix this problem, is there anyway to set it not affect the main open gl screen? thanks

Comment: I would need to see a bit more code for that one. Most likely you will need to rebind the main buffer after you are done drawing to the texture.

Comment: @MaticOblak dont understand what this mean, i updated the main post to add more code, please help, thanks

Comment: Are you creating a separate frame buffer or are you just using the same one? You should create an offscreen frame buffer, bind it, attach the texture. Then on draw bind the offscreen buffer, draw to it, bind your main frame buffer, draw the texture as full screen.

Comment: @MaticOblak  separate frame buffer, how can i rebind the original frame buffer when finish recording video,thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing some knowledge on how these things work and is impossible to know where your issue lies. Let me break down a few things for you so you may identify your issue, hopefully fixing it yourself but otherwise ask another question with a bit more specific parts of code showing what is working and what is not.

So to begin with the frame buffer, this object is a container for other buffers which in your case may be textures and render buffers. By binding a specific frame buffer you will tell the GPU to draw to the buffers that are attached to this frame buffer. The most common attachments are color, depth and stencil buffers. Most commonly the procedure of creating a new frame buffer will look something like this:

- Generate the new frame buffer to get the ID and bind it
- Generate a render buffer or a texture to get the ID and bind it
- Set the data and the format of the buffer using either `glRenderbufferStorage` or `glTexImage2D` or in iOS if you want to bind it to view you have `renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable:` on the `EAGLContext` object. (the last one might be done by some higher level object such as `GLKView`)
- Attach the render buffer to the frame buffer using `glFramebufferRenderbuffer` or `glFramebufferTexture2D`

This way you may create any number of frame buffers to which you draw. To chose which buffer to draw to you will simply need to bind the correct frame buffer.

Generally we split the frame buffers to main frame buffer and frame buffer objects (FBO). The main frame buffer is the one that represents your screen and has an ID of 0 so in most platforms you may simply bind a 0 indexed buffer to continue drawing to the main screen/view. BUT (and this is very important) on iOS there is no such thing as a main frame buffer from your perspective. You need to save the ID of the render buffer that is generated via `renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable:` and if this is not in your code (you are using higher levels of tools) you will need to ask the GPU for the buffer ID by calling

```
GLint defaultFBO;
glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING_OES, &defaultFBO);
```

(found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746602/getting-default-frame-buffer-id-from-glkview-glkit))
But you need to be sure you are calling this when your main buffer is bound, so preferably just before you start recording so you know it is the correct buffer.

Then FBO is any other frame buffer that is not main. It is also called an offscreen frame buffer. These are generally used for post-processing or pre-processing. In your case you use one to draw the pixels into the texture data which can very easily be accessed by the CPU with the texture cache described in the link you provided. So now you do have at least 2 buffers, the main buffer and the offscreen buffer. The offscreen buffer will have the texture which can then be redrawn to the main buffer. Now your basic pipeline on draw should look something like this:

- Bind FBO
- Draw the scene
- Process the FBO for video recording
- Bind main buffer
- Bind FBO texture
- Draw the bound texture to the main buffer

There are other ways as well such as

- Get data from media (camera, video...)
- Bind FBO
- Draw media data to FBO
- Process FBO for video recording
- Bind main buffer
- Draw media data to main buffer

This will draw the scene twice instead of reusing the same scene from the texture in the FBO. If you are not doing any heavy operations on drawing these are basically the same but it is still best to use the first one.

Comment: does this require a runloop, or does OpenGL somehow continue to append these frames into a pixel buffer at 60fps?

Comment: @rockyraccoon You need to be more specific but generally NO, nothing ever simply continues at 60FPS. But the same effect may be triggered by another system. For instance you may be getting sample buffers at usually 30 frames per second in real time which leads to a whole system to perform 30 times per second. But this has nothing to do with the openGL at all. OpenGL may work at any frame rate and in ideal situation you would get (way) more then 60FPS but you then limit it to 60FPS or to whatever is your screen refresh rate.